# Faulting application name: w3wp.exe Faulting module name: nlssorting.dll Exception code: 0xc00000fd

Tags: iis, w3wp.exe

On my development server I got following error.

> Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7600.16385, time
> stamp: 0x4a5bcd2b
>
> Faulting module name: nlssorting.dll, version: 4.0.30319.1, time
> stamp: 0x4ba1d8ae
>
> Exception code: 0xc00000fd
>
> Fault offset: 0x000020d5
>
> Faulting process id: 0xae4
>
> Faulting application start time: 0x01d049af7c9369d8
>
> Faulting application path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
>
> Faulting module path:
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\nlssorting.dll
>
> Report Id: 44dd0b77-b627-11e4-96f4-005056aa293f

Can any one told me what may be the issue or how can I identify what is the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug w3wp clr.dll error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335678/how-to-debug-w3wp-clr-dll-error)

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem with IIS Crash. 
The exception code "0xc00000fd" is a stack over flow, and likely there is a piece of code in your application that was throw this exception.

How you can identify this? I recommend that you catch a crash dump.

1) Install a software to get a crash dump. I recommend  the [DebugDiag Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42933).

2) After the installation, configure the **DebugDiag Tool** following these instructions:

- Selecting a Crash rule Selecting a IIS App pool (w3wp.exe)
- Selecting the app pool of application
- Configuring a Stack over flow
  exception (0xc00000fd) in Advanced Settings/Exceptions and finish 
  the setup.

3) Wait for a first crash dump to be created in folder location. Ex: C:\DebugDiag\Logs. When the crash dump was created, use the **DebugDiag Analysis** to open the file from C:\DebugDiag\Logs and a HTML report will be created.

4) In report you see quickly the problem in analysis summary on the top of the page. In my case, there was a recursive function without stop conditional that leading the app poll fall.

Comment: The link to DebugDiag Tools is broke. Do you mean https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49924 ?

Comment: Yes! But the update 1 is no longer available. You need install Debug Diagnostic Tool v2 Update 2.

Comment: Report needs to be opened with Internet Explorer (not Edge.)