# Dump Diagnostics

Tags: windows, iis, w3wp.exe

Recently i received the error log below in my windows Server 2012.

Some consequences like web site down happens and a 503 error are launching in the browser.

I caught up on updates in OS and i have searching for this problems, that let me to do some options like:

- Remove net.tcp, net.pipe, net.msmq, and msmq.formatname bindings
- Install KB2640103 hotfix, that needs to ask for Microsoft Support Customer.

I'm not an expert in Windows Server but would like to understand the situation and receive more comments.

**APPLICATION LOG**

> Log Name: Application Source: Application Error EventId: 1000
>
> Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 8.0.9200.16384, time
> stamp: 0x50108835
>
> Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.0.30319.18449, time stamp:
> 0x528fdca2 Exception code: 0xc00000fd
>
> Fault offset: 0x000000000010c0c5
>
> Faulting process id: 0x474
>
> Faulting application start time: 0x01d05204681c00ea
>
> Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
>
> Faulting module path:
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
>
> Report Id: 49a3bf22-bdf8-11e4-944f-22000afcadb1
>
> Faulting package full name:
>
> Faulting package-relative application ID:

**SYSTEM LOG**

> WAS
>
> Application pool 'v3.xxxxx.com.br' is being automatically
> disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that
> application pool.
>
> A process serving application pool 'v3.xxxxx.com.br' suffered a
> fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service.
> The process id was '4492'. The data field contains the error number.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I solved my problem in **5 steps**:

**1)** I installed a software to get a crash dump. In this case i downloaded the
[DebugDiag Tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49924).

**2)** I configured the DebugDiag Tool following these instructions in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18335759/4616202)
 . I didn't need to install WindDbg and Symbols.

> **After the installation it was configured in this way:**
>
> - Selecting a Crash rule
> - Selecting a IIS App pool (w3wp.exe)
> - Selecting the app pool of my application
> - Configuring a Stack over flow exception (0xc00000fd) in Advanced Settings/Exceptions and finishing the setup.

**3)** I waited for a first crash dump to be created in a folder location.  *Ex: C:\DebugDiag\Logs*  When the crash dump was created, i used the DebugDiag Analysis to open the file from *C:\DebugDiag\Logs* and a HTML report has been created.

**4)** In report was easy to see the problem. In my case, there was a recursive function without stop conditional. It was crashing the w3wp process.

**5)** Our team fixed the bug and solved the problem

Answer (score 3):

What you have tried is less relevant.

`0xc00000fd` means stack overflow. Thus, you need to review your code to see if it was caused by yours. If you were able to get a crash dump, that can provide more information about why it crashes.

Comment: Thanks Lex! Any idea to get a dump crash's details in production server? The application running without throwing exceptions in local machine, but if there is a piece of problematic code I need to catch it.

Comment: Do you have a support contract with Microsoft? If so, you can ping them to get assistance. If you are not aware of capturing dumps, I think you will also meet problems analyzing them.

Comment: Thanks! You opened my mind to solve this problem. I posted the solution,