# process serving application pool suffered a fatal communication error 5011

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5, w3wp.exe

Recently I encounter an issue which is related to http error 503 , service is unavailable. when I opened IIS I got that my application pool has stopped then I see windows logs and I see this message:

> a process serving application pool suffered a fatal communication error 5011.

The .NET Framework version being used is v4.0.
My site was worked correctly until yesterday but I don't know how fix this issue, thanks if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You are running into a classic application pool crash issue.

Please follow my [MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/parvez/2016/08/06/iis-application-pool-crash-and-debug-diag/) blog here to identify the culprit. Let me know if you need any help with this.

Comment: I found it here [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335678/how-to-debug-w3wp-clr-dll-error)

Comment: I'm having a similar issue but running the Debug application from the MSDN blog above effectively breaks the application pool and prevents anyone from using the site. Is there another way to debug these IIS crash iisues?