# Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Semantics.LangCompiler (Faulting application name: w3wp.exe , Faulting module name: KERNEL32.DLL)

Tags: asp.net, iis-8, crash-reports, w3wp

I am looking for a solution for 6 hours already. Please read before marking it duplicate. There are tens of other questions like this but none has valid answer that works on all.

My IIS 8 defaultapppool start crashing all of sudden after 5 threshold warnings of:

**A process serving application pool 'DefaultAppPool' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. The process id was '3604'. The data field contains the error number.**

And then this is the **Event Viewer Error** after 5 warnings

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 8.5.9600.16384, time stamp: 0x52157ba0

Faulting module name: KERNEL32.DLL, version: 6.3.9600.17415, time stamp: 0x545049be

Exception code: 0xc00000fd

Fault offset: 0x0001bb0b

Faulting process id: 0xd04
```

Yesterday: It crashed once and I just did right click on application pool > start.

Today: It crashed again around the same time (not exact). stopped every 5 minutes 6-7 times then start working normal until now.

Recycling is every 29 hours, and I don't think its recycling.

I installed DebugDiag to log crash dump after the last crash. With the instruction in https://stackoverflow.com/a/18335759/9357872 but no crash after that to see the results. But the regular ongoing log is indicating the following CLR Exception error:

DebugDiag Log:

```
CLR Exception on thread 4976. DetailID = 10
  ASP.global_asax on thread 4976. DetailID = 2

Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Semantics.LangCompiler on thread 4008. DetailID = 7
  Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Semantics.LangCompiler on thread 4008. DetailID = 7
  Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Semantics.LangCompiler on thread 4008. DetailID = 7
  Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Semantics.LangCompiler on thread 4008. DetailID = 7
  Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Semantics.LangCompiler on thread 4008. DetailID = 7
  Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Semantics.LangCompiler on thread 4008. DetailID = 7
  Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Semantics.LangCompiler on thread 4008. DetailID = 7
  Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Semantics.LangCompiler on thread 4008. DetailID = 7
```

I read that it is caused by using dynamics and memory leak; which I have never used in the whole website project

What is `Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Semantics.LangCompiler` ? I see there is something wrong in global.asax

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Just to throw this comment out:  Its not recycling.  Recycling causes a different EventLog message.  That event log message indicates your process crashed, so you're on the right track.

Comment: Honestly I would wait until you get the actual crash.  Troubleshooting some intermittent exceptions may not help you at all.  Those exceptions may have to do with your issue, but maybe won't.  When you do get the crash, with StackOverflow (which is what your error code indicates) you should get a function call repeated over and over on some thread.   Knowing that will help.

Comment: Debug Diag can tell you much more than just the crash, so unless you get a crash dump (second chance exception) there is something to discuss. First chance exceptions are so normal that it is pointless to track down everyone of them.

Comment: @LexLi I have crash rule for IIS web application pool with exception of stackoverflow, is this the right crash I'm waiting for?

Comment: @Rich-Lang I hope so, and the function calls will be regular function name right?

Comment: Hard to tell if what the function calls will be without the dump.

Comment: *You* may not have used `dynamic`... are you sure you aren't using any libraries doing the same?

Comment: @IanKemp libraries like?